# Rendering Date from model in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the date to render in a nice format. currently rendering like this

[image: rendered date]

I tried

```
  function getEndDateFromstring(){
    return itinerary.endDate.split('T').slice(-1)[0]
  }
```

then

```
{itinerary.name} from {getStartDateFromstring()} to {getEndDateFromstring()}
```

But it is throwing an error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Btw, I don't think it's necessary to upload an image to express less than 100 characters, please upload your errors or code in text format please.

Comment: Split can only be used on a string. you can try itinerary.endDate.toString().split('T').slice(-1)[0] or take a look at this question that goes through your question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: getDateFromstring
C:/Users/rach-/Homework/Get_Traveling_App/client/src/componets/ItineraryList/index.js:13
  10 |   showUsername = true,
  11 | }) => {
  12 |   function getDateFromstring(){
> 13 |     return itinerary.endDate.toString().split('T').slice(-1)[0]
  14 |   }
  15 | 
  16 |


This is the error I am getting when using the above provided by wowza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this

```
function addZeroIfOnlyOneChar(dateString){
    dateString = String(dateString);
    if(dateString.length < 2){
      return '0' + dateString
    }
    return dateString
  }

  function getDateFromString(dateString){
    const date = new Date(dateString)
    const day = date.getDate();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();

    
    return `${addZeroIfOnlyOneChar(day)}-${addZeroIfOnlyOneChar(month)}-${year}`
  }
```

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a scope issue, pass the `itinerary` to your function like below

```
  function getEndDateFromstring(itinerary){
    return itinerary.endDate.split('T').slice(-1)[0]
  }
```

and call like

```
{itinerary.name} from {getStartDateFromstring(itinerary)} to {getEndDateFromstring(itinerary)}
```